# Lian Li BS-08B Noise level?

Tags: fan, cooling

Wondering about the dBA on this piece:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811995027

It states that the fans are 1500 RPM and they are 120mm, so I'm guessing that it should be pretty quiet but I haven't seen anyone commenting on that specifically. Anyone have any experience with it or one of the sister products from Lian Li?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Silentpcreview](http://www.silentpcreview.com/) is an excellent source for information on low-noise to silent PC parts. They don't seem to have reviewed this particular model, but it's mentioned in a [forum thread](http://www.silentpcreview.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=458095).

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I think I saw that one or something similar with someone trying to replace the video card's original fan.  I'm looking more for just extra general exhaust in that part of the case.  Not even sure if I'm going to need it yet to be honest, as I'm waiting for all my parts to come in from newegg, but thought I would see if I could get any more info on this one. Also, since my case is a Black Lian Li, the part is a perfect match.

Comment: I'll give you the check mark for this anyway, the articles on that site are good and if I do end up ordering that particular part, I'll probably get a fan controller for my system as well, so the particular noise level of those fans should be controllable and I'm not expecting Lian Li to use a total crap fan, so that solves the problem, heh.